# Creating a search form that opens a new url based on search input

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, url, search

I created a form using bootstrap, you can see it below.
 [image: form]

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a user enter in a value (5 digits) and when they click on the "Search" button a new window opens displaying the search results. The url would depend on the 5 digits entered into the search bar. The only part of the url that changes for all searches are the numbers added in the search box.

http://monkey=13857&red

So for example, they enter 13857 in the search bar, and when they click on "Search" a new widow opens redirecting them to http://monkey=13857&red. I'm new to javascript but I think I would use it to accomplish this task - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

***--Update--***
Hi mwilson (and everyone who helped so quickly), I implemented the code (thank you for the help) and it seems like my code isn't adding in the search numbers to the url. Here is my form code

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">WorkFlow by Request ID</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Request #">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="WFF">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $('#WFF').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#search').text();
    var url = "http://monkey=" + searchInput + "&red";
    window.open(url);
});
```

If I enter 12345 in the search box and click the submit button it opens the site, but without the search entered- http://monkey=&red not http://monkey=12345&red

Comment: add the code that makes up the form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window.open(<url>)` to launch the window. Then it's just a matter of building the proper url string which can be done by creating a variable that holds the search value and the url. Build it how you need to and then pass it to the `window.open(<url>)` function and you're set.

**JQuery**

```
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#textBoxEl').val();
    var url = "http://monkey=" + searchInput + "&red";
    window.open(url);
});
```

**Just JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById("btnSearch");

button.onclick = function () {
    var text = document.getElementById("textBoxEl").value;
    window.open("http://monkey=" + text + "&red");
}
```

Comment: I think you should add javascript code for the OP. Since OP is new to Javascript, may have hard time getting into jquery

Comment: Hi mwilson, I implemented your code (thank you for the help) and it seems like my code isn't adding in the search numbers to the url. Here is my form code

Comment: Do you have a reference to jQuery in your HTML? If not, your code will not work. You will need to use the 'Just JavaScript' example.

Comment: I have added jQuery. I just added it and tested it, it works but this is the first real non-test command I'm trying out.

Answer (score 0):

write a javascript function like this,

```
function search()
{
var searchInput = document.getElementById('search').text();
var url = "http://monkey=" + searchInput + "&red";
window.open(url);
}
```

and call the function

```
<input type="button" onclick="search()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you actually need to build the URL that way... But typically Forms are "submit"ed. The receiving form has access to the data POSTed to it which you can use to run your search.
You can open in a new window by setting the form target = _blank.

```
<form target="_blank" action="monkey.html">
     <!-- your form here -->
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Import JQuery &
Try this code

```
$('#WFF').on('click', function () {
    var searchInput = $('#search').val();
    var url = "http://monkey=" + searchInput + "&red";
    window.open(url);
});
```

> Use `val()` instead of `text()`